# How to download attachment sent in Meeting invitation using Microsoft Graph API in UWP

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am working on a UWP app and using my personal ID for `authentication` purpose.
I have created few meetings with some `attachments`. I am trying to download those attachments using `Graph API`.

I called this API

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetAttachments
```

I am able to get the details about the attachment like name and size , but is there a way to `download` the attachment programmatically through the UWP app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/) for this rather than the legacy O365 REST APIs.

Graph supported returning a [list of attachments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_attachments) for a given event. From here you should be able to locate the URI for the [attachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fileattachment) you're looking to download.

Comment: do we have a sample URL call ? how do I do this ? any idea ?

Comment: The documentation I linked to includes the URI's you'll need to call. You need to do this is multiple steps, first get the list of attachments and then iterate over the results and fetch each attachment.

Comment: It helped a lot. Its such a tedious process. Attachments are available as a stream of bytes and not as a link :(